# Remove/change one child widget in a GtkGrid

Tags: c, gtk3

Is there a way to remove one child widget from a GtkGrid? There are functions to remove a whole row or column, but there is no `gtk_grid_detach()` or something. My goal is to change one widget to another if a condition changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use [gtk_container_remove()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-remove) to remove a widget from the grid. You need to hold a reference to it before you remove it if you want to keep it around after its been removed.